# Will the Windows SDK also support Spark?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have tried the Windows SDK to connect to the Spark and it does not work. 
Will the Windows SDK also support the DJI Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I fear if it ever will, it has a very low priority. The Mobile SDK only started supporting the Spark a couple of months ago, and the Windows SDK enum for product codes does not even contain the Spark as a value (in the documentation I have seen so far), even though this enum contains lots of products more than the currently only supported Mavic Air and Phantom v4 Pro... :-/

Answer (score 0):

There is no plan to support DJI Spark for Windows SDK.